# Text alignment in Java labels

Tags: java, jtable

I am developing a Java app centered on a table full of numbers.  In some columns, I would like to align the numbers (text, of course) in a column so that the decimal points are aligned vertically at the center of the cells.

I don't see any of the alignment constants which apply to this sort of situation.  Is there any official mechanism in Java to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Comment: I think that this may be doable by using a one line JTextPane with a decimal-aligned tab stop as the JTable cell renderer. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Createadecimalalignedtabstopat400pixelsfromtheleftmargin.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro at this, but it does work as I noted above by using a JTextPane as a custom cell renderer and setting tab attribute to be decimal-aligned.  If you do this, you must take care that the data is represented as a String and that when editing data that a tab character be prepended to the beginning of the data String.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TabStopDecimalAlign extends JPanel {
    private static final String[][] DATA = {{"One", "1.234"}, {"Two", "232.3223"},
    {"Three", "0.2323"}, {"Four", "12.345"}, {"Five", "10000.0"}};
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Count", "Data"};
    private static final int ROW_HEIGHT = 24;
    private DecimalAlignRenderer decimalAlignRenderer = new DecimalAlignRenderer();
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(DATA, COLUMNS);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model) {
        @Override
        public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
            if (column == 1) {
                return decimalAlignRenderer; 
            }
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        }
    };

    public TabStopDecimalAlign() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        table.setRowHeight(ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    private static class DecimalAlignRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        private static final float POS = 40f;
        private static final int ALIGN = TabStop.ALIGN_DECIMAL;
        private static final int LEADER = TabStop.LEAD_NONE;
        private static final SimpleAttributeSet ATTRIBS = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        private static final TabStop TAB_STOP = new TabStop(POS, ALIGN, LEADER);
        private static final TabSet TAB_SET = new TabSet(new TabStop[] { TAB_STOP });

        private StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument();
        private JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(document);

        public DecimalAlignRenderer() {
            StyleConstants.setTabSet(ATTRIBS, TAB_SET);
            pane.setParagraphAttributes(ATTRIBS, false);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value == null) {
                pane.setText("\t0.0");
            } else {
                pane.setText("\t" + value.toString());
            }
            return pane;
        }


    }



    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabStopDecimalAlign");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TabStopDecimalAlign());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a DecimalFormat object to make each number have the same count of digits after the decimal and just right aligning the column.

Comment: I will try this, but I've noticed that not all fonts allocate equal width to each character, so it may work sometimes and not others.